# React: setState with spead operator seems to modify state directly

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a page in React to filter attributes that are defined in my `state` with a `isChecked` like so:

```
this.state = {
    countries: [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Japan", "isChecked": false },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Netherlands", "isChecked": true },
        { "id": 3, "name": "Russia", "isChecked": true }
        //... 
    ],
    another: [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Example1", "isChecked": true },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Example2", "isChecked": true },
        { "id": 3, "name": "Example3", "isChecked": false }
        //...
    ],
    //... many more
};
```

I am creating a function `resetFilters()` to set all the `isChecked` to false in my `state`:

```
resetFilters() {
    // in reality this array contains many more 'items'. 
    for (const stateItemName of ['countries', 'another']) {

        // here i try to create a copy of the 'item'
        const stateItem = [...this.state[stateItemName]];

        // here i set all the "isChecked" to false.  
        stateItem.map( (subItem) => {
            subItem.isChecked = false;
        });

        this.setState({ stateItemName: stateItem });
    }
    this.handleApiCall();
}
```

My problem is: it seems I am directly modifying `state`, something that is wrong, [according to the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly). Even though my function seems to work, when I remove the line `this.setState({ stateItemName: stateItem });` it will also *seem* to work and when I console log `stateItem` and `this.state[stateItemName]` they are always the same, even though I am using the spread operator which *should* create a copy. My question: how is this possible / what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a producible example? https://codesandbox.io/, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the spread syntax does only shallow copying. If you want to carry out deep copying, you should also be spreading the inner objects within each array.

```
for (const stateItemName of ['countries', 'another']) {
  const stateItem = [...this.state[stateItemName]];
  const items = stateItem.map( (subItem) => ({
    ...subItem,
    isChecked: false,
  }));

  this.setState({ [stateItemName]: items });
}
```

Comment: Also, he should use square brackets around 'stateItemName' in the setState to replace the correct key on the state object, like this.setState({ [stateItemName]: items });

Answer (score 1):

I think your code could be reduced more so, for example an approach could be:

```
function resetFilters() {
  const targetItems = ['countries', 'another'];

  const resetState = targetItems.reduce((acc, item) => ({
    ...acc,
    [item]: this.state[item].map(itemArray => ({
     ...itemArray,
     isChecked: false
  }))
  }), {})

  this.setState(state => ({ ...state, ...resetState }), this.handleApiCall);
}
```

The benefit here is that the api call is done after state is updated. While updating current state correctly.

Let me know how it works out

-Neil

Comment: I like the idea of having a single `setState`. Somehow though, my state is not being updated, even though `resetState` seems to be correct.

Comment: Whoops this could be because resetState needs to be spread. Add three dots prior to usage. See updated code.

Comment: You are correct, it works when spread. do you know why this needs to be spread?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Yes, without the spread you would get `this.state.resetState.countries`, in a nutshell you want the properties to be at the same level as `this.state` not nested. If you are happy can I get a green check 